# What does this R symbol mean?

Tags: r, rstudio

[image]

I uploaded text to the fourth column for a topic model, but instead of text, this symbol is showing. When I hover over it, I can read the text; however, I want to make sure this symbol won't misguide my structural topic model analysis.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is this a picture of? Its better to share your data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) such as `dput()` so we can see what exactly is in there.

Comment: This might be an RStudio-thing, since R itself doesn't have GUIs (with alternating row-banding) like that, in which case I suggest the [tag:rstudio] tag would be appropriate. However, it could be a number of things including unicode (if in data). I'm not familiar with `stm` objects (I know they exist, I don't work with them) and I don't use RStudio, so hopefully somebody else with experience in both will "know" what it is without a reproducible example.

Comment: @r2evans is right - this is the RStudio Data Viewer, called by `View()` or by clicking on the dataset name in the Environment tab. Never seen that icon, though. @md_14 , what's the data type for that column? `class(<dat>$<col>)`

Comment: @AndreaM -Yes this is an RStudio Data viewer. The data type is a character. It's just odd because I've never seen this icon either.

Comment: could you run `str(<your_data>)` and see what it says? (Similar to @AndreaM's comment ...)

Comment: I just ran the topic model without issue. I think this symbol suggests that the cell contains a large text (e.g., pages of words). Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran the topic model without issue. I think this symbol suggests that the cell contains a large text (e.g., pages of words). Thank you all for your help!

Comment: This is useful, but it would be great if the answer could be enhanced with a pointer to some documentation somewhere (if it exists).