# Weird black paint-like symbol appears when reading a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a csv file in R but when I run read_csv(), I get this weird paint-like symbol for some rows, even though it is displayed correctly in the raw csv file. I have tried reading it through read.csv() and also converting the file to excel and reading it through read_xlsx() but I get the same weird symbol. I am guessing it has something to do with the encoding but I am not sure what to do. Any suggestions?

[image: image of the weird symbol]

Comment: From your image I would guess that your file is actually a JSON file. I would try to read it with e.g. `jsonlite::fromJSON`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this R symbol mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698311/what-does-this-r-symbol-mean)